# How to create socket connection over internet?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I have created a server-side and client-side console based Chatroom. I have done the port forwarding and also added the inbound rule to the firewall settings both in client-side and server-side. It is working fine with computers on the same network but when I connect to the server/socket with different network(mobile hotspot) it doesn't work. I know my public ip address and I have it tried using it also. I am using TCP connection and a port-'55555'. I have windows 10 os on my laptop. Also tried after disabling the virus protection, it didn't work.

Can you please suggest some ideas regarding how to make it work?

Comment: If the program works fine on your local network, this is not a programming problem that is suitable for [so]. You might want to ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) instead – be sure to check their question guides, though.

Comment: As you have told, I have checked on Super user. They were telling to use IPv6 or 
-> Have an externally reachable intermediate system with a real public IP (VPS, etc.) that you can use to facilitate communication between the two nodes. 

Don't know how to use IPv6 with my existing code and i don't understand the second option